# Probability to get the word "PHYSIK" from an urn representing the alphabet

Tags: probability

An urn contains $26$ balls. Each of them represents a letter of the alphabet, meaning that there are $21$ consonants and $5$ vowels.

We take $6$ balls from the urn (without putting back).

I want to calculate the following probabilities:

- $a)$ at most $3$ vocals are taken
- $b)$ the word "PHYSIK" can be created by the letters that are on the urns

I have the following:

a) $(\frac{5}{26})^6 = 0.005058012$%

b) $6 \cdot (\frac{1}{26}\cdot \frac{1}{25} \cdot \frac{1}{24} \cdot \frac{1}{23} \cdot \frac{1}{22} \cdot \frac{1}{23}) $

Is that correct or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so simple because the sampling is without replacement.

For (a) we calculate the probability of drawing four or five vowels and take the complement: $\frac{\binom{21}1\binom54+\binom{21}0\binom55}{\binom{26}6}=\frac{53}{115115}=0.046\%$. For (b) there is only one way to draw the letters in PHYSIK, so the probability is $\frac1{\binom{26}6}=0.00043\%$.

Comment: Thank you, but regarding $b$, we can also draw the letters like KISYHP, PHYSKI etc. or is that what you already mean with "there is only one way to draw the letters"?

Comment: @user10930711 With sampling without replacement we can draw all six letters at once - I have already accounted for that by using $\binom{26}6$ instead of ${}^{26}P_6$.

Comment: Okay. And what if the first ball contains a vocal? Do we have to use the binomial coefficient for the probability then as well?

Comment: No, I mean in general, not related to $a)$ or $b)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{26}^6$ for $b$?